# What is the use of the Bluetooth on iPad?

Tags: ipad, bluetooth

I would like to understand what other ways I can use Bluetooth on my iPad apart from connecting a physical keyboard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do peer-to-peer networking on bluetooth with some games and other applications.

I haven't checked out the details but my understanding is that the Bluetooth profile is much better in the iPhone 4 and iPad than in the early iPhones. I expect you could also hook up to BT headphones and speakers to stream music.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to P2P sharing and audio streaming like Doug said, if you have a jailbroken 3G one, you can create a wifi hotspot using [MiFi](http://rockyourphone.com/index.php/mywi.html).

Comment: In iOS it is now natively possible to create a Wi-Fi hotspot without Jailbreaking.

Answer (score 3):

Also, some emulators allow you to use a Wii controller via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

There are Bluetooth-to-IR devices ([for example](http://www.griffintechnology.com/beacon)) that let you control your TV and other devices from your iPad over Bluetooth.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This little gadget looks really good!

Answer (score 3):

## Tethering

You can “[tether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering)” your iPad to an iPhone to use its cellular data service as a “mobile hotspot”. For when you need internet access on-the-go.

You can do this via [WiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) as well. Using [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) instead may provide some advantages, such as saving on battery because the radio signal is weaker and needs less juice.

For details, see MacWorld article [*Use Bluetooth to tether your iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad*](https://www.macworld.com/article/1159258/smartphones/bluetooth-tethering.html) by Glenn Fleishman.

By the way, a third way to tether is via USB cable.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with **iOS 7**, Bluetooth on iPad (as well as other select iOS and Mac devices) can be used to exchange files and information wirelessly in an ad-hoc manner using a feature called [AirDrop](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204144).

Bluetooth is also employed when setting up and communicating with other Apple devices like [AirPods](https://www.apple.com/airpods), [HomePod](https://www.apple.com/homepod) and [Apple TV](https://www.apple.com/tv). With Bluetooth turned on, even a new iOS device can be easily set up by transferring content using an iOS feature called [Quick Start](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201269#quick).

Another interesting application with Bluetooth turned on is to easily share Wi-Fi password with nearby iOS devices belonging to saved contacts without entering it manually. Instructions can be found in the 9to5Mac article:

- [Easily share your WiFi with friends on iOS 11, automatically sends passwords to nearby devices](https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/06/ios-11-share-your-wifi/)

> iOS 11 includes many automatic features regarding first-time setup and account login. This extends to WiFi networks too. If a friend comes over with an iPhone running iOS 11, you can automatically log them in to your WiFi in one tap.

Comment: These are very cool uses. I always wanted to know how they detect these devices each other