# What can I do with an iPad Bluetooth-paired to a Mac?

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have successfully paired my iPad Gen 3 to my Mid-2012 MacBook Air. What can I do with this connection?

Answer (score 3):

I recently gave a presentation using Keynote on my MacBook and keynote remote on my ipad. This is a really cool solution that allows you to control slide movement on the MacBook while seeing both slides and presenter notes on the ipad.

Answer (score 1):

Not a whole heck of a lot, as it turns out, but which stems from the difference between iOS and OS X ... which it *seems* ought to talk to each other directly, but no. Not in the cards.

See this post: [What is the use of the bluetooth on iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-use-of-the-bluetooth-on-ipad?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an iPad with a cellular data connection, you can use [Bluetooth for tethering](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4517). It's likely more battery-friendly than using Wi-Fi.